# Samsung Note devices - Blank rows in the list view

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I am facing an issue on samsung note devices - specially note3,4,5.
I am seeing my list view like the screenshot attached where rows are not properly rendered i.e. blank rows but the rows actually do exists and tapping on it will take me to the next screen as desired. So it's a UI rendering issue only in note devices.

This is not reproducible every time.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my list view on note device]

Comment: It'd be helpful to see a screenshot of a working device as well as your layout xml

Comment: <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_messages_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />